# Multiple URL rewrites with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have below code in my .htaccess file, located in "root/mosaicin/" directory.,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mosaicin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(download-sample-papers|album|results|testimonials)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?url=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

I want to rewrite my url www.domain.com/mosaicin/album.php/NID/ to domain.com/mosaicin/album/NID/
Same for other pages listed in rule (results,testimonials etc.)

Sample code in my album.php file is like

```
<?php
$cid = NULL;
$url = new SimpleUrl('/mosaicin/');
if($url->segment(2) == FALSE)
    $cname = 'NID';
else
    $cname = $url->segment(2);
$cname = urldecode($cname);
$ccsql = "SELECT courseid,cname FROM courses WHERE cname='".$cname."'";
$csql = $obj->select($ccsql);
if(count($csql)>0)
$cid = $csql[0]['courseid'];
?>
```

After getting courseid my code works to list items related to particular course.
Currently when I go to page 
tplabs.in/mosaicin/album.php/NID everything works fine, but with link below
tplabs.in/mosaicin/album/NID it gives 404 error.

Please help,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which links you want to goto `/download.php` and which ones to `/gallery.php` You need to understand you cannot have `/anything` going to both scripts.

Comment: Actually I found this code from php url-rewrite class, could not understand it but i guess it rewrites all urls to downloads.php, but what I want now is to rewrite urls starting with downloads.php?cid=1 to /1/download.php
and gallery.php?cid=1 to /1/gallery.php
Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Better would be this pretty URL scheme: `/download/1` to `/downloads.php?cid=1` and `/gallery/1` to `/gallery.php?cid=1` Let me know if you're okay with this and I will post my answer.

Comment: Yes this is also okay, please post answer, thanks

Comment: ok posted an answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try these rules in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /mosaicin/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^(download-sample-papers|album|results|testimonials)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?url=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

Comment: 1. I made mistake of using `download.php` instead of `downloads.php` (corrected now) and 2. You need to place above code in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` 3. Your links should be `http://domain.com/downloads/1`

Comment: I have dir sturcture as root/mosaicin/
and so .htaccess file is in mosaicin dir itself.
I have tried to set RewriteBase, but its not working.
I still have to use URLs with .php extension,
http://tplabs.in/mosaicin/album.php/NID/
This below url is not working
http://tplabs.in/mosaicin/album/NID/

Comment: Sure that I can help with but I don't get what is `/album/NID` since my answer only takes care of `/downloads/123` and `/gallery/567` I just need to what are all the URLs you want to display on your site

Comment: Previously I wanted to display ID only, but then Name would be more readable and good for keyword SEO. so instead of 1 i will create link of NID, 2 for NATA and so on.

Comment: Ok understood but can you clarify and list  all the URLs you want to display on your site and what should be their internal URLs.

Comment: It would be diffcult to list all, but samples are like,
album/NID/
album/NIFt/
album/NATA/

and same for other dynamic pages like, downloads, courses, testimonials and results

Comment: No I don't want list of each URL but just like to know each URL type like 1) `/downloads/fo` => `/downloads.php?url=foo` 2) `/gallery/bar` => `/gallery.php?url=bar` etc

Comment: Yes, so that list is like
1) download-sample-papers/foo => download-sample-paper.php?url=foo 
2) album/foo => album.php?url=foo
3) results/foo => results.php?url=foo
4) testimonials/foo => testimonial.php?url=foo

Comment: Actually current link is , album.php/NID , without any redirection rule. Can we just redirect it to album/NID ?

Comment: Ok I updated the answer as per your previous comment. Make sure it is in `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess`.

Comment: Hi, can you please explain me once, how does it work?
the link tplabs.in/mosaicin/album/NID is still not working, its gives 404 error.

Comment: If you have .htaccess in `mosaicin` then see updated answer again.

Comment: Hi, its still not working :( . I already tested it with RewriteBase too. See the updated question for more clarification and file code.

Comment: Hmm okay see updated answer. Basically `$1.php?url=$2` instead of `/$1.php?url=$2`